# Unit testing async functions in node/express

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js

I am looking for the cleanest pattern to test middleware that contains async code using Mocha, Node's assert library, and Sinon. Here's a paired-down example of the function I'm testing.

```
function some_middleware(req,res, next){
    var input = req.body;
    if (some_test(input)) {
        lib.async_function(input)
            .then((returned_object) => {
                res.locals.data = returned_object;
                res.render('stop-list');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                res.render('message', {message: err})
            })
        }
    else{ next() }
}
```

None of these functions return the promise returned by `lib.async_function()`. Returning the promise would make testing in Mocha much easier. We could just change:

```
... 
return lib.async_function(input) 
...
```

we could test like this use:

```
it('Should responsd set locals.data to fetched object', function(){
    // Stubs -- most of this goes in a beforeEach block but here for the example
    var res = {render: sinon.stub(), locals: {}}
    var req = {body: "returned_value" }
    var next = sinon.stub()
    var async_stub = sinon.stub('lib', async_function)
    async_stub.resolves(fakedata.stoptimes)

    next.throws("Next Shouldn't be called")
    return some_middleware(req, res, next)
    .then((ret) => assert.equals(res.locals.data, "returned_value" ))

})
```

**Question one:** Is it a bad practice to insist functions return a value, which isn't required, simply to make testing easier? Are there any side effects of this?

If making all the async middleware functions return a promise is a bad idea, we can still design tests, but they start to get a little wordy. For example, we could use the stubbed out `res.render()` and test like this:

```
it('Should responsd set locals.data to fetched object', function(done){
    // Stubs
    var res = {locals: {}}
    var req = {body: "returned_value" }
    var next = sinon.stub()
    var async_stub = sinon.stub('lib', async_function)
    async_stub.resolves(fakedata.stoptimes)

    next.throws("Next Shouldn't be called")
    res.render = result => {
        try {
            assert.equals(res.locals.data, "returned_value" )
            done()
        } catch (e) {done(e)}
    }
    some_middleware(req, res, next)

})
```

We need to wrap the assert in a `try/catch` block otherwise `done()` never gets called when the test fails and the test times-out. This seems like a lot of code for such a simple test. Which leads to:

**Question two:** is there a better way or an accepted best-practice that gracefully handles test failures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a bad practice to insist functions return a value, which isn't required, simply to make testing easier? Are there any side effects of this?

I wouldn't say it's bad practise, having to provide anchors for test purposes isn't uncommon. Side affects would really boil down to how & where it's being used, in this case it looks very much like [Express middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) and nowhere in the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) does it mention any rules about not returning values. Furthermore, if you dig into the [source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js#L86) you'll find that middleware return values are ignored.

I think in your case returning a Promise from the middleware is the ideal solution.